# Constructing multi-arch rpm packages with Open Build Service

Tags: package, rpm, opensuse, meego

I have the following questions about building and constructing RPM packages correctly:

1. Where could I find some deep explanations about using **baselibs.conf** file in RPM packages?
   I've found these small pieces: http://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:Build_Service_baselibs.conf.
2. Is this file used only by OBS server or somewhere else?
3. Has any difference between building rpm package with baselibs.conf locally and remotely on OBS server? - means when I build locally I get only following packages: **.src.rpm and .dontuse.rpm**, but when I build remotely I get extra **.rpm** package - which is the most important.
4. How can I check locally that configurations in baselibs.conf are correct?